# What is the exception thrown in a running .NET thread when Windows shuts down?

Tags: .net, multithreading, shutdown

The exact exception message would be helpful, too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ThreadAbortException

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

Be careful trying to catch or stop that. It's very tricky.